# Chi square and zscore - chose which one?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, recommendation-engine, chi-squared

I posted question on [stat stack exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125242/chi-square-and-zscore-chose-which-one) but unfortunately got no answer so far, so I clone it here and do hope someone can help.

I'm newbie in machine learning. Recently I tried to learn something on this and got following concern:

I have products classed by categories. Also I have users with gender and device model information.

First, I made a chi square test to check whether categories and gender + device information are associated. For example, my p-value is 0.000012 so I stated that the user (gender + device) is associated with categories.

So if a new user come with his gender (Female) + device (iPhone):

1. As the chi square test result, there should be an association between gender + device and categories. So I select top 10 categories that were consumed by Female who using iPhone. I've got the list, e.g. [1. Fashion, 2. Mobile devices 3. Cameras, 4. Home furnitures, 5. Bikes, etc.]
2. I also make a z-test on categories (without any user information), and got the list (higher z-score will be on top), e.g. [1. Mobile devices, 2. Bikes, 3. Fashion, 4. Laptops, etc.]

So in this case, which list should I give to that user? Or any possibility to combine them? Or did I do something wrong?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, none of the tests is appropriate. In both tests you have a *null hypothesis* (that gender and model is not related to category), and you are trying to find the probability that this hypothesis is wrong. However, theses two tests are *parametric tests*, that is for the results to be correct you have to know that the probability follows a specific distribution (chi square and normal distributions respectively). In your case you can make no such assumption, so the tests are not suitable. If you want to use significance tests, you should use a *non-parametric tests*, Wilcoxon and Friedman tests being the most common. However, significance tests are usually used *after the problem has been solved* to check if the results achieved can be attributed to luck. They are not used to solve the problem.

If you want to find correlation between gender, model and category, you should use some correlation coefficient, such as *Pearson correlation* and *intraclass correlation*. However, you have not described your data in detail, so I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Based on gender and model only, probably the safest and simplest thing you can do is return the most visited categories (number of occurences) by women who use iPhone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  

1. Can you please explain why two of my data are not chis square / normal distribution?  
I'm not so sure that using two user data of device + gender as parameters for chi square test is a right thing or not (can you please explain why this should not be the right one?). But how about the z-test for number of users consumed the categories? As far as I understand, this is probably a normal distribution.  

2. Yeah, select the most visited categories is safe and simple, but this might not be the best matches for user? Any other advice?

Thanks so much :-)

Comment: 1) Both the tests you use are statistical significance tests, and they are used to check if two variables follow the same distribution. They mostly used for comparing sets of results, not finding correlations. To find a correlation, the most common metric is Pearson's. 2) Since the z-test compares two sets of variables, I don't know how you combine gender and phone in one attribute. However, neither follows a normal distribution (since they are unordered, nominal values)

Comment: 1. I've heard about Pearson's correlation but don't think it's applicable in my case. Can you please explain how?      
2. No, I did the z-scores separately for gender and phone models on the number of consumptions of each category. However I never thought normal distribution elements must be ordered :S